# Getting unknown error about "dynamic accessors failing" after updating to macOS

Tags: objective-c, xcode, macos, cocoa, macos-sierra

After upgrading to macOS Sierra (10.12) and Xcode 8.0 (8A218a), I began getting many error messages in my macOS/Cocoa app (written in Objective-C) that follow this format:

```
[error] warning: dynamic accessors failed to find @property implementation for 'uniqueId' for entity ABCDInfo while resolving selector 'uniqueId' on class 'ABCDInfo'.  Did you remember to declare it @dynamic or @synthesized in the @implementation ?

[error] warning: dynamic accessors failed to find @property implementation for 'uniqueId' for entity ABCDContact while resolving selector 'uniqueId' on class 'ABCDContact'.  Did you remember to declare it @dynamic or @synthesized in the @implementation ?

[error] warning: dynamic accessors failed to find @property implementation for 'uniqueId' for entity ABCDEmailAddress while resolving selector 'uniqueId' on class 'ABCDEmailAddress'.  Did you remember to declare it @dynamic or @synthesized in the @implementation ?

[error] warning: dynamic accessors failed to find @property implementation for 'address' for entity ABCDEmailAddress while resolving selector 'address' on class 'ABCDEmailAddress'.  Did you remember to declare it @dynamic or @synthesized in the @implementation ?
```

None of this is my code or code from 3rd party developer libraries that I'm using, and doing a search on those variable names (i.e: 'uniqueId' or 'ABCDInfo') does not pull anything up, indicating it's not in my project.

I saw that this issue was also reported on Apple's Developer Forums twice ([Issue 1](https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/64189) and [Issue 2](https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/64274)), but both questions remain unanswered

My question is: What causes these error messages and how can I fix them? 
It doesn't cause my app to crash, but I'd rather figure out and understand what's wrong.

Comment: I'm having the same problem, but I'm looking for an answer Swift. Thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

First of all let´s check what @synthesize and @dynamic are:

- @synthesize will generate getter and setter methods for your property
- @dynamic tells the compiler that the getter and setter methods
  are implemented not by the class itself but somewhere else (like the
  superclass or will be provided at runtime)

Contacts now requires that anyone using mail/contact framework needs to be codesigned with the uses-contacts entitlement.

You need to sandbox your app by granting the "Contacts access" entitlement. The warnings will still be logged, but this is linked to another bug of XCode 8 that logs so many things uselessly.

It seems Apple will no longer accept non sandboxed app to access the Contacts (or location or calendar).

To sandbox your app do the following:
Go to your project settings > Select your app > Enable App SandBox and then select the App data that you´re using.

Comment: If you don't plan to distribute the app via the App Store because you need sandbox to be off, you still can enable the contacts entitlement, and then manually revert the sandbox value to NO in the plist.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe related to this configuration:

- You are accessing AddressBook framework, probably built with 'implicit synthesized properties' ON.
- You software is built with 'implicit synthesized properties' OFF

Comment: How would I turn off "implicit synthesized properties" in the AddressBook framework?

Comment: @RyanD'souza You can't, because it's already compiled. You have to turn this option on.

Comment: I tried, still getting the error messages logged (while the functionality works fine)